# $|G|=p^nm$ and number of subgroups of order $p^s$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We suppose that $G$ is a finite group such that $|G|=p^nm$ and $(p,m)=1$ ($p$ is prime). If $s\le n$ and $r_s$ is the number of subgroups of $G$ with order $p^s$, I want to prove that $r_s$ is congruent to 1 $mod \ p$.

I have already proved, using the class equation, that if $|G|=p^n$ then $r_s$ is congruent to 1 $mod \ p$. I think we may use this and a Sylow theorem to get what we want, but I haven't found a proper way.

Could you give my a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: The Wielandt proof of Sylow's Theorem proves this.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention the Sylow theorems, I assume you already know $r_n \equiv 1 \mod{p}$. Let $1 \leq s \leq n-1$.

Let $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_{r_{s+1}}$ be subgroups of order $p^{s+1}$ in $G$. For each $i$, let $p_i$ be the number of subgroups of order $p^s$ in $P_i$.

Let $Q_1, Q_2, \ldots, Q_{r_s}$ be the subgroups of order $p^s$ of $G$. For each $i$, let $q_i$ be the number of subgroups $P_j$ that contain $Q_i$. Then

$$q_1 + q_2 + \cdots + q_{r_s} = p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_{r_{s+1}}$$

Now $q_i$ is equal to the number of subgroups of order $p^{s+1}$ in $N_G(Q_i)$, so by induction $q_i \equiv 1 \mod{p}$. You already mentioned that you know $p_j \equiv 1 \mod{p}$. Then the equation above implies $r_s \equiv r_{s+1} \mod{p}$, and so $r_s \equiv 1 \mod{p}$ by induction.

Comment: This proof also works if you know $r_1 \equiv 1 \mod{p}$, because $q_i$ is also equal to the number of subgroups of order $p$ in $N_G(Q_i)$. You can prove $r_1 \equiv 1 \mod{p}$ with McKay's proof of Cauchy's theorem

Comment: "Now $q_i$ is equal to the number of subgroups of order $p^{s+1}$ in $N_G(Q_i)$, so by induction $q_i \equiv 1 \mod{p}$." For this, may I know how does the induction apply?

Comment: I guess that this is because $N_G(Q_i)<G$. But I can't find a contradiction if $N_G(Q_i)=G$, that is $Q_i \lhd G$

Comment: @AlanWang: The proof goes by downwards induction: base case is $s = n$, and we prove the result for $1 \leq s < n$ by assuming the result for $s+1$ (and applying it to $N_G(Q_i)$).

Comment: Can we apply this to $G$? Are we making the assumption that $r_{s+1}\equiv 1 \bmod p$?

Comment: @AlanWang: In the end of the proof we do: the argument is that $r_s \equiv 1 \mod{p}$ since $r_s \equiv r_{s+1} \mod {p}$ and $r_{s+1} \equiv 1 \mod{p}$.

Comment: @AlanWang: Perhaps I could have written this more clearly four years ago. Anyway, the induction assumption is that for *any* finite group, the number of subgroups of order $p^{s+1}$ is $\equiv 1 \mod{p}$. So that applies in particular to $N_G(Q_i)$. The base case is that the number of Sylow subgroups in any finite group is $\equiv 1 \mod{p}$.

Comment: I think I am clear now. But one more question: Does any subgroup of order $p^{s+1}$ in $N_G(Q_i)$ contains $Q_i$?

Comment: @AlanWang: That seems not to be true in general, and probably that means this answer is not quite correct. (I will edit it later.)